# ES/OS : Terms aggregation on bucket key substring

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, opensearch

I have the following query result and I want to count the substring after delimiter `:`

```
                "agg_by_script" : {
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
                  "buckets" : [
                    {
                      "key" : "mic:cse",
                      "doc_count" : 2
                    },
                    {
                      "key" : "ggl:cse",
                      "doc_count" : 20
                    },
                    {
                      "key" : "amz-ret",
                      "doc_count" : 1
                    },
                    {
                      "key" : "ety:onr",
                      "doc_count" : 1
                    }
                  ]
                }
```

And from this result I actually want below

```
"agg_by_company_type" : {
 "buckets" : [
 {
    "key" : "ret",
     "doc_count" : 1
 },
 {
   "key" : "cse",
    "doc_count" : 2
 },
 {
   "key" : "onr",
    "doc_count" : 1
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use terms aggregation with script. This is an example query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "agg_by_company_type": {
      "terms": {
        "script": """
          String txt = doc['FieldName'].value;
          if(txt.indexOf(':') > -1 ) {
            return txt.splitOnToken(':')[1];
          }
          else if(txt.indexOf('-') > -1 ) {
            return txt.splitOnToken('-')[1];
          }
          else {
            return txt;
          }
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can do any string operation in the script according to your needs.